# Why is the following k8s command and args syntax wrong?

Tags: kubernetes

Why is the following k8s command and args syntax wrong?

**this is wrong**

```
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    args:
    - sleep
    - '36000'
```

**this is ok**

```
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    args:
    - sleep 36000  or  'sleep 36000'
```

Comment: Because shell's `-c` parameter expects exactly one value. Run `sh -c sleep 1` vs `sh -c 'sleep 1'` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed a multi-line shells script in your manifest, your best bet is probably to use the YAML block literal operator (`|`):

```
command:
  - sh
  - -c
  - |
    echo "this is a multi-line shell script"
    sleep 300
    echo "beep boop bingle"
```

There's no particular reason to have separate `command` and `args` entries in this case. This would be equivalent to the above:

```
command:
  - sh
  - -c
args:
  - |
    echo "this is a multi-line shell script"
    sleep 300
    echo "beep boop bingle"
```